# Installing Eclipse and setting up Android ADT on OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, adt

I am trying to install Eclipse Galileo on my MacBook running OS X v10.6 (Snow Leopard) and set it up with ADT plugin. I downloaded 64-bit cocoa version of "Eclipse Galileo for Java EE developers" and ADT v0.9.6 from the respective offical sites. 
When I try to add this new plugin-archive in Eclipse, I get the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because
>   one or more required items could not
>   be found ....missing requirement: ADT
>   requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core
>   0.0.0' but it could not be found.

AFAIK, one gets this error when a required Eclipse-plugin is missing. I checked the official site and saw that wst-plugin is actually bundled with "Eclipse for Java EE developers" download package [compare Eclipse packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php). Not sure what I am missing here.

EDIT: My mac is not connected to the internet so I guess adding resource URLs to the "Available Software sites" section wouldn't help. I would have to download anything required on my PC and then copy it onto my mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Setting up Eclipse without internet connection is very tough; getting hands on the zip archives for package dependencies, downloading them manually and everything is pain. So, I connected my mac to internet and let Eclipse calculate the dependencies and download them for me. Everything seems to have worked out just fine.

BTW, I had the following two URLs in the "Available Software Sites" section(these are added by default):
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/ and
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.5

I downloaded the archived ADT plugin from :
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/adt_download.html

cheers!

Comment: i have the same problem .. and it gives the same error .. ive tried in both the ways but nothing solved it .
i am connected to the internet and eclipse didnt find any dependencies