# installing eclipse ide 3.5 for android development

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i got the error 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0 missing when i tried to install the adt plugin for android

Comment: What OS are you using?
Which package of Eclipse did you install? 
"Eclipse for JEE" usually has that plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

Right, this is usually an Eclipse packaging problem where the default installation fails to include the basic paths.

You will need to add "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo" to the available software sites.  See [http://android.opensourceror.org/2009/12/07/missing-dependencies-for-the-eclipse-adt-plugin](http://android.opensourceror.org/2009/12/07/missing-dependencies-for-the-eclipse-adt-plugin/)/ for a complete walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

One of the required Eclipse plugin is missing([see similar thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486416/installing-eclipse-and-setting-up-android-adt-on-os-x-v10-6-snow-leopard)). Which package of Eclipse did you install? "Eclipse for Java EE" usually has that plug-in. Alternatively, you can add Eclipse release and update sites in the "Available Software Sites" panel and let Eclipse handle the required-plugin download for you.